# How to prove a function is continuous, injective and that its image is S1

Tags: general-topology

Consider the application $f: [0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, defined by $f(t)=e^{2i \pi t}$. With $\mathbb{S}^1$ defined by $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that the $|z| = 1$.

Verify that $f$ is continuous, injective and that its image is $\mathbb{S}^1$.

Then show that the inverse of $f$ is not continuous.

I know that the graph of $\mathbb{S}^1$ looks like a circle, but any help with the rest?
please and thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Some hints:**

- Continuity follows from the fact that $f(t)$ is the composition of several continuous maps.
- Injectivity follows from the rule $e^z=e^w \Longleftrightarrow z \equiv w $ (mod $2 \pi i)$
- For all $T<1$, the image $f \left[[0,T] \right]$ is a circular arc (connected subset of the circle) of length $2 \pi T$. Thus $f \left[ [0,1) \right]$ is connected and has length $2\pi$.
- It is enough to show that $f$ isn't an open map.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an open arc $(\theta_1, \theta_2)$ in $S^1$. Can you see that its inverse image is $(t_1,t_2)$? 
For injectivity , notice that $e^{i2\pi t}=(cos\pi t, sin\pi t)$ is a parametrization of the circle. To see that the inverse is not continuous, notice that $S^1$ is compact, while $[0, 1)$ is not. The continuous image of a compact space is compact. Notice that if $f^{-1}$ was continuous, then you would have a homeomorphism between the non-compact set $[0,1)$ and the compact space $S^1$ , which is not possible.